# AWS hosted Direct Connect connect through ISP

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I need to have a 5 gbps Direct Connect connection to my Amazon VPC from my servers residing at a ISP data-centre.

I can't wait for more than 1 week to set it up. Is it possible through a hosted Direct Connect connection to get the 5 gbps?

Answer (score 0):

From [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/WorkingWithConnections.html)

> Port speed
>
> AWS Direct Connect supports two port speeds: 1 Gbps: 1000BASE-LX
>   (1310nm) over single-mode fiber and 10 Gbps: 10GBASE-LR (1310nm) over
>   single-mode fiber. You cannot change the port speed after you've
>   created the connection request. If you need to change the port speed,
>   you must create and configure a new connection.
>
> For port speeds less than 1 Gbps, you cannot request a connection
>   using the console. Instead, you can contact an APN partner who
>   supports AWS Direct Connect and who can provision a hosted connection
>   for you.

So basically: if you need 5Gbps, buy 10.